# Struct memory allocation

Tags: c, assembly

I am studying structs on C with Assembly. I write following code and compiled to assembly with`gcc -Og` .

```
struct test {
    short *p;
    struct {
        short x;
        short y;
    } s;
    struct test *next;
};


void st_init(struct test *st){
    st ->s.y  = st->s.x;
    st->p = &(st->s.y);
    st->next = st;
}
```

And it gave me following assembly code :

```
st_init:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    movzwl  8(%rdi), %eax
    movw    %ax, 10(%rdi)
    leaq    10(%rdi), %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rdi)
    movq    %rdi, 16(%rdi)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

I understood the first 4 line of the assembly. But I think that in last line, there should be 12(%rdi) instead of 16(%rdi).

Why?
If I lay down the test struct's memory layout

```
|--------|--|--|--------|
0        8  10 12       20
     p     x  y    next
```

each - indicates a byte. According to this layout start byte of next is 12th byte, so it should be 12(%rdi). Am I wrong ?

Comment: If `st->s.x` is not initialized, the assignment `st ->s.y  = st->s.x` is meaningless. The assignment `st->next = st` might be meaningless as well, but might not be depending on the type of list you're creating.

Comment: You're neglecting the fact that there is padding between the nested structure and the `next` member.  Remember, various data types (such as pointers) may have alignment restrictions that necessitate internal padding in a structure.  Try printing out the addresses of the various structure members, e,g. `printf("%p\n", (void *) &st->next);`  Also print the total structure size.  It's not what you think.

Comment: The size of the struct is 24 bytes. I understood that because of data alignment, the remaining 4 bytes from s are passed and memory allocation for next is started from the top of next 8 bytes. Am I right ?